# face recognition using tracking.js

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

On the client side(HTML) using webcam i need to detect the face and process the face image in the middleware(python) once the processing is done the relavant name of the face has to be tagged to the face detected in the webcam.

Using tracking.js i am able to detect the face but unable to do the face recognition in the server side(python)

How each detected frame can be sent to the server from tracking.js?

How can the response (person name) from the middleware be tagged to the face detected in webcam?

i tried using webhooks but am unable to send the detected frame to the server.

using javascript, i tried with the below code script.

```
window.onload = function() {
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var c=document.getElementById("image_canvas");
      var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
      var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');
      tracker.setInitialScale(4);
      tracker.setStepSize(2);
      tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

      tracking.track('#video', tracker, { camera: true });

      tracker.on('track', function(event) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
          context.strokeStyle = '#FFFAF0';
          console.log(rect);
          context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
          context.font = '11px Helvetica';
          context.fillStyle = "#fff";
          context.fillText('x: ' + rect.x + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 11);
          context.fillText('y: ' + rect.y + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 22);
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 180, 180);
          ctx.drawImage(video, rect.x+50, rect.y-20, rect.width+160, rect.height+180, 0, 0, 180, 180);


         var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = "/createreg";
         var params = 'imageData:'+ctx;
         http.open("POST", url, true);
         http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

         http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
        }
         }
        http.send(params);
```

**On the python Side iam trying to read the image object**

```
@app.route('/createreg', methods=['POST'])
#@token_required
def createreg():
        print('-----3.1---',request.form['imageData'])
```

Iam unable to read the image object from the server(app.py)
Pls suggest the way forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most difficult part you already did, that is detecting the face in front side.

Once you got it, proably this api/framework tracking.js should have an event like onFaceDetected or onImageCaptured that you can use to send the captured face to the server.

Probably on back side you have a web service that will receive the image (face) and will process it and return the respose, and the image will be a data structure, like a json containing the image in base64. So to accomplish the result you want, you need on the event get the image in the format needed (bytearray, base64, etc), build a json with it and send using ajax to the webservice, getting the result and updating the ui via javascript.

Comment: I added the code script pls suggest what best can be done to send the detected face as part of POST request.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Is there something about getting this data in a encoded way? My experiences with CV libraries were with OpenCV, and I remember that to cut a picture just with the face and get the data we use the rect points to do the cut and get the image. Maybe you can do something like that, and use this strategy to get the base64 from image: https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/

Comment: For server side I'll let others help you, because I have almost no one knowledge in python